# How can I use gitlab users and admin authentication using AD (LDAP) in a self hosted Linux envrionment?

Tags: gitlab

I am using RHEL9 in a self-hosting situation.  We are new to the gitlab paradigm coming in from plain old git.

I am able to get regular gitlab users to authenticate using AD however I want folks to have admin access to be able to login that way too without the need of making separate accounts.  I tried everything left and right and I am at my wits end.  Any help getting me past this hurdle is appreciated.  Thank you.  Below is my gitlab.rb relevant snippet.

Everything is obviously obfuscated so don't use names like they are gospel with how IO named them originally.

```
##! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'FOOBAR AD'
     host: 'foobar.com'
     port: 389
     uid: 'sAMAccountName'
     bind_dn: 'foobar-gitlab@foobar.com'
     password: 'ff32a30c3af5012ea395827a3'
     encryption: 'plain' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
     verify_certificates: true
     smartcard_auth: false
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: false
     lowercase_usernames: false
     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=com'
     user_filter: 'memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=foobar-gitlab-   
users,ou=foo,ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=com)'
 #     ## EE only
      group_base: 'ou=foo,ou=baz,dc=foobar,dc=com'
      admin_group: 'foobaz-gitlab-admins'
    EOS
```

Thank you!